# Output RSS feed as html?

Tags: php, javascript, rss, feed

Are there any free php/javascript libraries out there which would help in displaying an RSS feed as html?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my Opinion  [Simplepie](http://simplepie.org)  is one of the Best RSS parsers.

**Here is an example:**

```
require_once('simplepie.inc');
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://simplepie.org/blog/feed/');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();


    <?php foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 5) as $item): ?>

        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>
            <p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/wiki/) might help, here -- quoting [its FAQ](http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/what_is_simplepie), it's :

> - A code library, written in PHP, intended to make it ridiculously easy
>     for people to manage RSS and Atom
>     feeds.
> - An easy to use API that handles all of the dirty work when it comes to
>     fetching, caching, parsing,
>     normalizing data structures between
>     RSS and Atom formats, handling
>     character encoding translation, and
>     sanitizing the resulting data.

Of couse, it will not do **everything** for you -- but it might help you get started.

Other solutions include, for instance, [`Zend_Feed_Reader`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.reader.html) or [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: certainly a much cleaner approach than rss2html. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try [Magpie RSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/). It can parse RSS feeds to arrays which you can easily iterate through and build your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually a library either, but I would definitely recommand you to use [XSL/XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).