# RSS feed generation and implementation

Tags: php, javascript, rss

I am a fresher to Rss feeds.

I have read some sites related to rss feed.But i didn't get full picture about it.

I understand that ,i need to create a xml  for displaying my site contents as feed  in another site.

**For example**

i have two php sites

1. www.site1.com
2. www.site2.com

And there is page feed.xml in site1.com, which has the latest feeds

Let me know  , what are the general methods to display these feeds to other site www.site2.com

Also , where can i see the general format of xml used for rss

Comment: There's a related link on the side of this page which points to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037351/output-rss-feed-as-html). That should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On www.site2.com

- Fetch RSS using a RSS library from www.site1.com
- Parse
- Display

You can use Simplepie RSS library for this purpose. See http://simplepie.org

Answer (score 0):

See [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Example) for the general format.

You can find PHP-RSS-Parsers [HERE](http://simplepie.org/), [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp) or [HERE](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/).